what is a continuation?
what is You apparently haven't filed a continuation. by @Gary S?
could anyone teach me? I was not allowed to ask in the thread, so I open a new thread if possible.
A final patent was granted, but in the process of a licensing deal, another claims first to file

A continuation application is a new application with filing fees to pay all over again. The content is usually the same specification as the original but with different claims.
The claims can be amended later, possibly by your licensee’s lawyer to address their specific issues.
A continuation must be filed during the pendency of the parent application and indicate that it is a continuation.

Thanh you, George, that can ONLY be done when your application was not published? I got this reminder from my UK examiner. I choose to amend my claims instead of withdrawing it and  re-application. -----"22.
Alternatively, if you wish to add technical information to your application,
you can withdraw your current application before it is published and file a new
application. As mentioned above, if you file a new application within 12 months of
your current application's filing date"  and I didn't get her feedback in 3 months, does it means my application will be published accordingly?

A continuation can be filed after publication but can’t add new matter. What you have quoted says that if your application is lacking technical information you can file a new, better, and get priority to the first application. If this is done before publication your first application will not be used against your second application.

HI @George, great thanks, I will continue with my first application, I didn't get her reply after 2nd amendment of claims, I suppose it is OK this time, ay least meet the standard, this is her 2nd comment: "I have re-examined your application in response to your letter of September
and I am of the opinion that it still does not comply with the requirements of the
Patents Act.

Do you won’t get a patent.

Hi George, what do you mean? this is her 2nd reply, and I amend the claims greatly, I didn't get her response after 3 months now.

Did you made amendments after that letter ? If so maybe it’s fixed.  But patents are very hard even for knowledgeable experienced people.
